Mongoose Error - Can't call openUri() on an active connection
I hope you are okay. I am trying to write some tests for my application and I am fairly new to node.js, mongoose, and js in general.
I have this dbconnection file:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const logger = require("../utility/logger");
const config = require("config");
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require("mongodb-memory-server");

let mongoServer;

async function connectDB() {
   if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 0) {
      await mongoose.connection.close();
   }

   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
      if (!mongoServer) {
         mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
         const mongoUri = mongoServer.getUri();
         await mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
      }
   } else {
      const url = config.get("db");
      await mongoose
         .connect(url)
         .then(() => logger.info(`Connected to DB: ${url}`))
         .catch((err) => logger.error("Could not connect to DB.", err));
   }
}

async function disconnectDB() {
   if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 0) {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
      if (mongoServer) {
         await mongoServer.stop();
      }
   }
}

module.exports = { mongoose, connectDB, disconnectDB };


And the test that I am trying to make it work:
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../../../app"); 
const { User } = require("../../models/userModel"); 
const {
   connectDB,
   disconnectDB,
} = require("../../../src/startup/dbconnection");

describe("User Authentication", () => {
   let userPayload;

   beforeAll(async () => {
      await connectDB();
   });

   afterAll(async () => {
      await disconnectDB();
   });

   beforeEach(() => {
      userPayload = {
         firstName: "John",
         lastName: "Doe",
         email: "john.doe@example.com",
         password: "password123",
         phoneNumber: "1234567890",
      };
   });

   it("should register a user and authenticate the user", async () => {
      
      let res = await request(app).post("/api/auth/register").send(userPayload);

      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
      expect(res.body).toHaveProperty("email", userPayload.email);

      res = await request(app).post("/api/auth/login").send({
         email: userPayload.email,
         password: userPayload.password,
      });

      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
      expect(res.body).toHaveProperty("token");
   });

   it("should fail authentication with incorrect credentials", async () => {
     
      await request(app).post("/api/auth/register").send(userPayload);

      const res = await request(app).post("/api/auth/login").send({
         email: userPayload.email,
         password: "wrongPassword",
      });

      expect(res.status).toBe(400);
      expect(res.text).toContain("Invalid email or password");
   });
});


I always get this error:
 MongooseError: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections


I have rewritten dbconnection file several times. I have the env set to test, I  check if there is an existing connection and if there is to force close it. I am not sure what can I do. I've tried debugging with gpt as well but gpt(gpt4) seems to either have old stuff in it or just doesn't comprehend  the problem at hand.
Please help, thank you!
